# SQL Json_value alternative in GraphQL with Hot Chocolate

Tags: sql-server, graphql, .net-6.0, hotchocolate, json-value

I have a table with a string column that is formatted as json. I want to query my table by json. This is achievable with SQL

```
SELECT * 
  FROM [db].[dbo].[table]
  WHERE JSON_VALUE(ColName, '$.jsonkey') = "value"
```

Is it possible with GraphQl and Hot Chocolate?

I tried

```
public IQueryable<Class> GetById([ScopedService] AppDbContext context, string id)
        {
            return context.Classes.AsQueryable().Where(p => JObject.Parse(p.JsonCol)["id"].ToString() == id);
        }
```

Got an error:

> "message": "The LINQ expression 'DbSet()\r\n    .Where(p =>
> JObject.Parse(p.JsonCol).get_Item("id").ToString() == __id_0)' could
> not be translated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using EF Core? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#json-columns

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you, I looked it up - looks promising. I'll give it a try.